# Access denied for user 'host'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, sql, macos

MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'host'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

i have the correct password but after trying to connect my app with sql i get this error

```
 cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUES(%s)",('M'))
 mysql.connection.commit()
```

From the responses  online i should reset my password. I tried it like this:
and after i try to reset it with :

1.) cd /usr/local/mysql/bin

2.) ./mysql -u root -p
3.) i type in my password

now no error

Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Only in the app I am trying to do.

Comment: how are you declaring your connection?, Have you confirmed the username and user privileges?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to connect with username **host**, hence the *Access denied for user '**host**'@'localhost'* error message.

With the command line you connect with the root user. Can you confirm you're using the correct username in your application?

Comment: im using this configuration:                                                                               
 #Configure db
db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']
mysql = MySQL(app)

Comment: and the db.yaml file is like this :                                                                 
 mysql_host: 'localhost'
mysql_user: 'host'
mysql_password: 'xxxxxxx'
mysql_db: 'my_database'

Comment: If you have an user called host then it's all right

Comment: Make sure you have a user called **host** with sufficient access permissions. Looking at your question it looks like if your database user is **root**. Beware of using this user because it could be a security issue.